# Insert values in a column from a query with another table with matching id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

**Cust360** :

```
Customer_id int primary key,
Gender nvarchar(50),
Basket_count int null,
```

**Transactions** :

```
Cust_id int,
Transaction_id int,
tran_date datetime,
total_amt int
```

I have to insert values in `Basket_count` from the transactions table with the 
COUNT of DISTINCT purchases where multiple purchases in one day is equal to 1 Basket.

```
SELECT COUNT(tran_date)
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY tran_date, cust_id
HAVING COUNT(tran_date) > 1
```

I want to insert these values in cust360's `Basket_count` column where the
`cust_id` from `transactions` matches with that of cust360.

Comment: you group by tran_date,cust_id,this means same cust_id will have more than 1 result.but you customer_id is a primary key in cust36?

Comment: What troubles are you facing with that? And which one RDBMS of two mentioned?

Comment: Its MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: I am having troubles in updating basket_count values as per the query above. I want to set the basket_count row value where the customer_id matches

Comment: I have updated my Answer since OP confirmed SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to perform an `INNER JOIN` in your `UPDATE` statement on the `Customer_id` and `Cust_id`. You've tagged the question as both `MySQL` and `SQL Server` RDBMS, so the structure is a little different.

**MySQL example:**

```
UPDATE Cust360 c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Cust_id, COUNT(t.tran_date) cnt
    FROM Transactions t
    GROUP BY t.tran_date, t.cust_id
    HAVING COUNT(tran_date) > 1) t2 ON c.Customer_id = t2.Cust_id
SET c.Basket_count = t2.cnt;
```

**SQL Server (Transact/T-SQL) example:**

```
UPDATE c
SET c.Basket_count = t2.cnt
FROM Cust360 c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Cust_id, COUNT(t.tran_date) cnt
    FROM Transactions t
    GROUP BY t.tran_date, t.cust_id
    HAVING COUNT(tran_date) > 1) t2 ON c.Customer_id = t2.Cust_id
```

[[SEE MySQL DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/ERYFD3795)

[[SEE TSQL DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/MAI52047)

---

[image]

---

Additionally, let's say you now want to collect the `SUM()` of the `total_amt`, you could add a column to your Cust360 table named `TotalAmount` and then:

**MySQL example:**

```
UPDATE Cust360 c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Cust_id, COUNT(t.tran_date) cnt, SUM(t.total_amt) total
    FROM Transactions t
    GROUP BY t.tran_date, t.cust_id
    HAVING COUNT(tran_date) > 1) t2 ON c.Customer_id = t2.Cust_id
SET c.Basket_count = t2.cnt,
    c.TotalAmount = t2.total;
```

**SQL Server (Transact/T-SQL) example:**

```
UPDATE c
SET c.Basket_count = t2.cnt
    , c.TotalAmount = t2.total
FROM Cust360 c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Cust_id, COUNT(t.tran_date) cnt, SUM(t.total_amt) total
    FROM Transactions t
    GROUP BY t.tran_date, t.cust_id
    HAVING COUNT(tran_date) > 1) t2 ON c.Customer_id = t2.Cust_id
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please re-write one in sql server script